# "Операторный" рефакторинг

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

У меня есть различные операции сравнения <, >, = для переменных double в моём коде.
Но теперь хочу немного изменить логику сравнения (например, сравнивать числа c какой-либо точностью). Для этого я реализовал отдельные методы расширения класса double.

Как теперь мне "отрефакторить" свой код? Т.е. заменить все операции сравнения (только для double-величин) на соответсвующие методы? Или всё же придётся обшаривать весь код?

Comment: Конечно, можно было бы переопределить операторы сравнения для double, но такое, к сожалению, невозможно в последней версии языка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Вам придется находить все операции сравнения и заменять их на `extension` методы *в случае необходимости.* Собственно, найти все референсы на `double` должно быть не так уж и сложно.
- Вообще говоря, это лучше, чем *где-то там* перегрузить глобальный оператор сравнения, поскольку при чтении кода теряется ясность.

> В варианте с `double.EqualsWithEpsilon(double)` сразу становится понятно, что конкретно для данного случая необходимо осуществлять сравнение с учетом точности. В противном же случае можно представить себе, что скажет вслух другой программист, узнав, что у него `0` и `0.1` посчитались как *равные* из-за того, что вы перегрузили глобальный оператор `==` с точностью `0.1`

Comment: По-моему, это параноидально. Тем более, что проверка **равенства** действительных чисел особого смысла не имеет (спасибо IEEE за это!)

Comment: У меня задача - поиск решений СЛАУ итерационными методами. Там все сравнения нужно производить с точностью, поэтому вот такой вот и вопрос